# elasticsearch edgengram copy_to field partial search not working

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, n-gram

Below is the elastic search mapping with one field called hostname and other field called catch_all which is basically copy_to field(there will be many more fields copying values to this)

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "myNGramFilter": {
                  "type": "edgeNGram",
                  "min_gram": 1,
                  "max_gram": 40
            }},
            "analyzer": {
                "myNGramAnalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "myNGramFilter"]
                }
            }
        }
  },
    "mappings": {
      "test": {
        "properties": {
          "catch_all": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "store": true,
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        },
                        "grams": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "store": true,
                            "analyzer": "myNGramAnalyzer"
                        }
                    }
          },
          "hostname": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "catch_all"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

When I do the

```
GET index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "myNGramAnalyzer",
  "text": "Dell PowerEdge R630"
}
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "d",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "de",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "del",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "dell",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "p",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "po",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "pow",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "powe",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "power",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "powere",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "powered",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "poweredg",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "poweredge",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "r",
      "start_offset": 15,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "r6",
      "start_offset": 15,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "r63",
      "start_offset": 15,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "r630",
      "start_offset": 15,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a token called "poweredge".
Right now we search with below query

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "fields": ["catch_all.grams"],
      "query": "poweredge",
      "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

When we query with "poweredge" we get 1 result. But when we search by only "edge" there is no result.

Even the match query does not yield results for search word "edge".

Can somebody help here ?

Comment: ho do you search against "catch_all.grams"? Could you provide a sample of your data with poweredge in text field?

Comment: @Lupanoide updated the question with query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to don't query with multi_match api for your use case, but to use a match query. The edgengram works in that way: it try to make ngram on the tokens generated by a whitespace tokenizer on you text. As written in documentation - [read here](http://The%20edge_ngram%20tokenizer%20first%20breaks%20text%20down%20into%20words%20whenever%20it%20encounters%20one%20of%20a%20list%20of%20specified%20characters,%20then%20it%20emits%20N-grams%20of%20each%20word%20where%20the%20start%20of%20the%20N-gram%20is%20anchored%20to%20the%20beginning%20of%20the%20word.):

> The edge_ngram tokenizer first breaks text down into words whenever it
>   encounters one of a list of specified characters, then it emits
>   N-grams of each word where the start of the N-gram is anchored to the
>   beginning of the word.

As you have tested in your query to analyze API, it doesn't product "edge" - from poweredge - as ngram because it products ngram from the beginning of the word - look at the output of you analyze API call. Take a look here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/ngrams-compound-words.html

Comment: I used match query as well on "catch_all.grams" field which does not return result for "edge".  That is the main issue.

Comment: ok, i have answered on it. Also in your call api - GET index/_analyze - you can observe that it doesn't return "edge" from the process of edge ngram tokenization, right? Please read better my answer and visit the documentation page of ngram-compound-words